# How do I plot my function?

Tags: plotting

```
f[x_, nm_] := 
  N (2/Sqrt[Pi]) 
    (Sum[
       (-1)^n Gamma[2*n - 1]/Gamma[n + 1] t^( 2 n + 1) 
         MittagLefflerE[v, 2 n + 2, (-d^(v) t^v)], 
       {n, 0, nm])
```

Here `N, d, v` are constants and `nm` is limit of summination which is infinity.

I need to plot this

Comment: 1.  Typo in last line.  2.  This seems to evaluate to the constant $\frac{2N}{\sqrt{\pi}}$.

Comment: `N` can't be used as a constant because it is a built-in function.

Comment: A small tip: Don't use N as a constant; N is a built-in function in Mathematica that turns exact numbers into floats. [sniped by @ChrisK]